# sql query filter with subset properties

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I use sqlalchemy to work on an mysql database.
I have a table something like this:

```
=============================================
id  user_name   time  status         content2
=============================================
1   a           1      approved      x
2   a           2      open          y
3   b           1      rejected      g
4   b           3      open          h
```

I want to find out all rows that are in approved status but are not the latest for the given user. For example, row with id=1 is in approved status but a later report from same user exists. I want to filter such rows as (1).

I am able to do this only by first filtering all rows with status=approved and then find if there is any row for the same user and date later. This is very slow. I am looking for a faster alternative that can be done in a single query.

Comment: A simple join will suffice

Answer (score 0):

All rows in approved status but not the latest for a given user:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable outer
WHERE status = 'approved'
AND id <> (SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable inner WHERE inner.user_name = outer.user_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
inner join 
(SELECT MAX(id) FROM MyTable) as mt 
on mt.id=id where status = 'approved'
```